# php actualiza la contraseña si actualizo otros datos del perfil

Tags: php, html, mysql, android

estoy creando el formulario de editar usuarios mi problema es que al momento de actualizar otros datos del usuario por ejemplo el nombre o correo, el campo de la contraseña se actualiza en la base de datos me agrega otro hash ya que estoy usando password verify para encriptar, luego no puedo acceder al sistema porque la contraseña en la base de datos es otra, quiero saber que estoy haciendo mal.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme, por favor? Gracias

```
<?php
include('autenticacion.php'); 
if(isset($_POST['update_usuario'])) 
{
    $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $role_as = $_POST['role_as'];
    $status = $_POST['status'] == true ? '1':'0';

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido', email='$email', password='$password', role_as='$role_as', status='$status' WHERE id_usuario='$id_usuario' ";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Se actualizó correctamente";
        header("Location: registro.php");
        exit(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: En tu sentencia **UPDATE** añades esto ```password='$password'```, es decir, tu mismo lo actualizas, elimínalo si esto no lo deseas: ```$query = "UPDATE usuarios SET nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido', email='$email', role_as='$role_as', status='$status' WHERE id_usuario='$id_usuario' ";``` Te aconsejo que uses sentencia preparadas.

Comment: Lo que tienes es un gravísimo error de concepto, pues se lee esto en tu pregunta: *ya que estoy usando password verify para encriptar* lo cual no es correcto. `password_verify` NO se usa para encriptar, se usa **para verificar** que la contraseña es correcta, cosa que debes hacer y no haces. El problema no se resuelve simplemente quitando la columna password del `SET`, debes: 1. Verificar que la contraseña proporcionado es correcta con `password_verify`; 2. Si lo es, hacer el UPDATE, pero sin incluir la contraseña, como te indica @DBE. Y, haz caso a su consejo de usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: @A.cedano tienes razón, esta todo un poco confuso lo que quiere hacer con el **password**, si te fijas en el código en cambio sí usa ```password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);```  , aunque dice como tu mencionas *password verify* , aunque simplemente comparando en el WHERE el email, debería ser suficiente para actualizar el usuario, ya que debe ser *unique*.

Comment: @DBE en teoría no debería bastar con el email, pues alguien que conozca el email podría modificar los datos, para este tipo de operaciones se debería pedir la constraseña y verificarla. En cuanto a `password_hash` se usa al momento de crear la contraseña (cuando el usuario se registra). Aquí `password_hash` no tiene ninguna razón de ser, lo único que hace es arrojar confusión. Otra cosa sería en un código donde el usuario estuviera cambiando la contraseña, pero no es el caso, esa es precisamente la queja de OP, pues no quiere que la contraseña sea modificada.

Comment: @A.Cedano si ese detalle se me paso por alto, en eso te doy toda la razón, yo lo hago así siempre. Aunque muchas veces se queda guardada XD

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['password'] && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $queryUpdatePassword = "UPDATE usuarios SET password='$password'";

}
```

Solo mete dentro de un condicional si meten envían password que se actualice, si no lo envían que no haga nada.

Y lo mismo en la consulta con un if si ya cachaste que si te están enviando password creas la actualización.